# 7z An Existing Tar File

Tags: tar, 7z, p7zip

I am on ubuntu 20.04 and I have a `71GB.tar` file that I would like to 7zip before moving it to long-term storage.

I can create a new `directory.tar.7z` using:

`#tar cf - directory | 7z a -si directory.tar.7z`

However, I cannot

`#7z a -si directory.tar.7z`

It just freezes.... no errors...

How can I 7zip *pre-*existing tar archives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell 7z to create a new archive containing the tarball:

```
7z a directory.tar.7z directory.tar
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> #7z a -si directory.tar.7z
> ```
>
> It just freezes.... no errors...

It does not freeze, it waits for data on its stdin. `-si` means "read data from stdin" (and it made sense in case of `tar … | 7z a -si …`). BTW, how is the command that allegedly freezes supposed to know you want to compress `71GB.tar`?

If you want to stick to `-si`, you can provide the file via stdin:

```
<71GB.tar 7z a -si directory.tar.7z
```

but `7z` will store it inside the archive as `directory.tar`. You can specify a name though:

```
<71GB.tar 7z a -siArbitraryName directory.tar.7z
```

The easiest thing is not to use `-si` at all:

```
7z a directory.tar.7z 71GB.tar
```